# pass argv[] from main to other class

Tags: constructor, parameter-passing, argv

Hi I have a question about passing argv[] value to the other class. In my code, I want to pass the argv[1] parameter from cmd to the class mainWindow to trigger spacific event. Here is the code. #include "MainWindow.h"

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    #if _DEBUG
        // Do not print memory leaks at end of program (QtWebKit causes a large number of them, see Menu class)
        _CrtSetDbgFlag(_crtDbgFlag &~ _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    #endif

    QApplication  app(argc, argv);

    app.setApplicationName("Example_Qt");

    MainWindow window;
    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

---

```
MainWindow.cpp
```

---

```
MainWindow::MainWindow() :
    m_pCurrentTutorial(0),
    m_pCurrentTutorialAREL(0)
{
    setupUi(this);

    quitTutorialButton->setVisible(false);

    QObject::connect(quitTutorialButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onQuitTutorialButtonClicked()));

    m_pMenu = new Menu(this, this);

    // Init the main view for the scene using OpenGL
    QGLWidget *glWidget = new QGLWidget(QGLFormat(QGL::SampleBuffers));
    m_pGraphicsView = graphicsView;
    m_pGraphicsView->setScene(m_pMenu);
    m_pGraphicsView->setViewport(glWidget);
    m_pGraphicsView->setFrameShape(QFrame::NoFrame);

    // Do not show context menu in web view
    m_pGraphicsView->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::NoContextMenu);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete m_pMenu;
    m_pMenu = 0;

    delete m_pGraphicsView;
    m_pGraphicsView = 0;
}
```

Mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <vector>

#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QWebView>

class TutorialBase;
class TutorialBaseAREL;
#include "Menu.h"

#include "ui_MainWindow.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
class QGraphicsView;
class QBoxLayout;
QT_END_NAMESPACE


class MainWindow : public QMainWindow, public Ui::MainWindow, public Menu::TutorialSelectionCallback
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow();
    virtual ~MainWindow();

    QBoxLayout* getButtonBar();

protected slots:
    void onQuitTutorialButtonClicked();

protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);

    void quitTutorialIfAny();

    void startTutorial(int tutorialNumber);

    void startTutorialAREL(int tutorialNumber);

    TutorialBase*               m_pCurrentTutorial;
    TutorialBaseAREL*           m_pCurrentTutorialAREL;
    QGraphicsView*              m_pGraphicsView;
    Menu*                       m_pMenu;
};


#endif
```

Could anyone help me to pass the parameter from the argv[] to mainwindow.cpp ?

Many thanks

Ying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just provide another constructor (or replace the current one) which takes a single `char *` argument, such as:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow (char *arg) :
    m_pCurrentTutorial(0),
    m_pCurrentTutorialAREL(0)
{
    // body here, including checking argument, such as:
    if (strcmp (arg, "-help") == 0) {
        provideHelp();
    }
}
```

and then use *that* constructor when creating your object:

```
MainWindow window (argv[1]);
```

Be aware that this new constructor will need to be listed in the class (in `Mainwindow.h`), not just added as a function to `Mainwindow.cpp`:

```
public:
    MainWindow();
    MainWindow(char*);
    virtual ~MainWindow();
```

Comment: But there returns errors when I modify the constructor. Here is the mainwindow.h Would you please have a look?

Comment: @saul203, you'll have to also add the new constructor to the class declaration (probably in the header file) as well.

Comment: Should I add the class declaration into class MainWindow : public QMainWindow, public Ui::MainWindow, public Menu::TutorialSelectionCallback
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow();
    virtual ~MainWindow();

Comment: @saul203, yes, that's correct. I've updated the answer with some more detail.

Comment: @saul203, you _accept_ an answer by clicking on the green tick mark, which you've already done by the looks of it. You _vote_ by clicking the arrow above the score (to vote up) or below the score (to vote down). I'm telling you about both but it would be unusual to accept then downvote an answer :-)

Comment: @saul203, actually you need 15 rep to vote up. Accepting an answer on your other question will _just_ get you there.